# Cypher MERGE being too slow

Tags: csv, merge, neo4j, cypher

I have a CSV file with about 15 million rows. I am trying to import them with `CSV IMPORT` but it's taking too long.
When I try to import them with `CREATE` they get imported in a decent amount of time, but that creates a lot of duplicates. So, I tried to use `MERGE` instead but it's taking a lot of time. The query was running for more than 10 hours before I terminated it. After that I tried to import just few columnsand waited more than 30 minutes before I terminated the query. Here is the code for running just the few columns:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///companydata.csv' AS line1

MERGE (company:Company {companyNumber:line1.CompanyNumber,
                        companyName:line1.CompanyName,
                        uri:line1.URI
                          })
```

My question is: does MERGE usually behave like this or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the name of your input file (`companydata.csv`) and the columns used in the `MERGE`, it looks like you're misusing `MERGE`, unless the URI is really part of a composite primary key:

1. Match on a unique key
2. Set the properties

Otherwise, you'll be creating duplicate nodes, as a `MERGE` either finds a match with all criteria, or creates a new node.

The query should probably look like

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (c:Company) ASSERT c.companyNumber IS UNIQUE;

USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///companydata.csv' AS line1

MERGE (company:Company {companyNumber: line1.CompanyNumber})
SET company.companyName = line1.CompanyName,
    company.uri = line1.URI;
```

The unicity constraint will also create an index, speeding up lookups.

---

**Update**

There's a comment about how to address nodes which *don't have* a unique property, such as a `CompanyInfo` node related to the `Company` and containing extra properties: the `CompanyInfo` might not have a unique property, but it has a unique relationship to a unique `Company`, and that's enough to identify it.

A more complete query would then look like:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (c:Company) ASSERT c.companyNumber IS UNIQUE;

USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///companydata.csv' AS line1

MERGE (company:Company {companyNumber: line1.CompanyNumber})
SET company.companyName = line1.CompanyName,
    company.uri = line1.URI
// This pattern is unique
MERGE (company)-[:BASIC_INFO]->(companyInfo:CompanyInfo)
SET companyInfo.category = line1.CompanyCategory,
    companyInfo.status = line1.CompanyStatus,
    companyInfo.countryOfOrigin = line1.CountryofOrigin;
```

Note that if `companydata.csv` is the first file imported, and there are no duplicates, you could simply use `CREATE` instead of `MERGE` and get rid of the `SET`, which looks like your initial query:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (c:Company) ASSERT c.companyNumber IS UNIQUE;

USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///companydata.csv' AS line1

CREATE (company:Company {companyNumber: line1.CompanyNumber,
                         companyName: line1.CompanyName,
                         uri: line1.URI})
CREATE (company)-[:BASIC_INFO]->(companyInfo:CompanyInfo {category: line1.CompanyCategory,
                                                          status: line1.CompanyStatus,
                                                          countryOfOrigin: line1.CountryofOrigin});
```

However, I noticed that you mentioned trying `CREATE` and getting duplicates, so I guess you do have duplicates in the file. In that case, you can stick to the `MERGE` query, but you might want to adjust your deduplication strategy by replacing `SET` (last entry wins) by `ON CREATE SET` (first entry wins) or `ON CREATE SET` / `ON MATCH SET` (full control).

Comment: It is working faster like this but I don't always have property that needs to be unique. For example I have this in my query:
`MERGE (companyInfo:CompanyInfo {category:line1.CompanyCategory,
                                status:line1.CompanyStatus,
                                countryOfOrigin:line1.CountryofOrigin,
                                  })
MERGE (company)-[:BASIC_INFO]->(companyInfo)` .
None of the properties in CompanyInfo needs to be unique so I don't know where to MERGE and where to SET properties.

Comment: The company is unique, and I guess there's a unique `CompanyInfo` per `Company`? That's enough to work on, I'll update the answer with that extra example.

Comment: This way it creates duplicate `CompanyInfo` nodes. Let me give you an example of what is going on:
There is a company named "Zoza Unlimited" which has a relationship BASIC_INFO with CompanyInfo that has properties: `countryOfOrigin:United Kingdom, category:Private Limited Company, status:N/A`. There is another company named 'ABC Unlimited' and has relationship BASIC_INFO with CompanyInfo that has the same properties as the other node. So, there are two nodes with same properties instead of one CompanyInfo node with those properties and both of the companies being linked to the same node.

Comment: You could have said `CompanyInfo` nodes where shared... In that case, yes, merging on all the properties would be the only way _with that model_, which is not very graph-y (that could be a lot of combinations and `CompanyInfo` nodes). What could be more graph-y would be to use `Country` nodes, `CompanyCategory` nodes, etc. to which the `Company` nodes would directly connect to, and you'd be able to find similar companies for any number of criteria. I don't know your use case, but does `CompanyInfo` have a meaning by itself?

Comment: `CompanyInfo` Does not have meaning by itself. So, your suggestion is to divide CompanyInfo to several nodes? Let's say a Company node with property `countryOfOrigin:United Kingdom` and all the companies from United Kingdom being linked to that node? would then this query be ok: `MERGE (companyCategory:CompanyCategory{category:line1.CompanyCateg‌​ory})
 MERGE (company)-[:HAS_CATEGORY]->(companyCategory) 
MERGE (companyCountry:CompanyCountry{country:line1.CountryofOrigin})
 MERGE (company)-[:HAS_COUNTRY]->(companyCountry)`
I am used to relational databases so this is confusing to me :)

Comment: IMO that's a much more graph-y and versatile model: because you can have multiple relationships of the same type, you don't need the equivalent of a junction table for a many-to-many association. Don't forget to create the unicity constraints for each label!

Comment: Thank you very much for all the help.
I will mark this as solved.

Comment: may i know if the `on create` is not essential before `set`?

Comment: @mingchau it depends on what you want to achieve: the `SET` becomes conditional when using `ON CREATE`.

Comment: Yeah I got it now. When use `set` without `on creat` it means will set the properties on the matched.